# Hibernate Criteria How get only one parent if child is the same for another

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am using Hibernate `Criteria` to get parents with some child by condition.

```
 Criteria criteria = sessionProvider.getSession().createCriteria(Parent.class);
 criteria.add(Restrictions.in("child", childs));
```

It works correct, but I want to do some optimizing to reduce time of the retrieving.

So It need to get only one parent object if child is presented in another.
For example.

**Query** adove has return this:

```
Object<Child@7711> //the same child for parent
Object<Child@7711> //the same child for parent
Object<Child@1193>
Object<Child@1195>
```

What does it need add to `Restriction` to get only one Parent if child is the same(share)?.

Result must be as here:

```
Object<Child@7711> //the same child for parent
//*ignored because child exist in other parent*
Object<Child@1193>
Object<Child@1195>
```

Comment: well, how would you do it in plain sql?

Comment: I am looking to simple effective way :)

Comment: if you manage to do it in plain sql, you will be able to do it with criteria as well